# Using the CWAC get Picture from javascript

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I would like to access the CWAC library from javascript . From phonegap I would like to replace the navigator.getPicture() with the CWAC equivalent ? How do i do that ? Is that possible at all ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could write a Cordova/PhoneGap plugin that would use the library. Most likely it would not literally replace `navigator.getPicture()`, by which I mean that `getPicture()` would not trigger the plugin. But there would be some other way to trigger the plugin that you could use instead of `navigator.getPicture()`.

However, I have never written such a plugin, and I am not aware of anyone who has written a plugin that uses this library. Hence, most likely, you would need to write the plugin yourself.